# Argparse: set default text file

Tags: python, argparse

I am looking to set a text file `rand.letter.txt` as the default word file in this argparse segment, to be used and read in the program. I would assume this should be situated in row 4-5 down below. How should I do this?

As you will see I have already done that with the matrix size. But I am struggling when in regards of a file with str characteristics.

```
def main():
    print("WELCOME TO THE MEMORY PUZZLE!")

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Memory game") 
    parser.add_argument("words_file", metavar="FILE", nargs=1,
                        help="Words file")

    parser.add_argument(
        "--matrix-size",
        metavar="SIZE",
        dest="matrix_size",
        help="Matrix size",
        default=6,
        type=int,
        )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    game = Game(args.words_file[0], args.matrix_size)
    game.play()
```

Thank you so much for any help or input!

Comment: Have you tried adding `default="rand.letter.txt"`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately its does not work, returns that it is missing a file if I dont include one when i start the program (which I am looking to not have to do), "error: the following arguments are required: FILE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a default postional argument you need to specify the [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) as `?`. This will consume one argument from the command line, if available, otherwise the default will be used.

```py
parser.add_argument(
    "words_file", nargs="?", default="rand.letter.txt", help="Words file"
)
```

Also, when you initialise your `game` you are slicing the first character off the `words_file` variable. You need to change it to:

```py
game = Game(args.words_file, args.matrix_size)
```

Notice the `[0]` is gone.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is that I get this message: " FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r' " When I dont type in any argument (since I just want the defaults): 
(venv) n147-p63:Project rebeckae$ python3 game.py

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set default values for positional, you have to specify `nargs="?"` [Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default). `nargs=1` seems to be superfluous in your example anyways, since it only produces a list of one item. So your line should look like this:

```
parser.add_argument("words_file", metavar="FILE", nargs="?",
                        default="rand.letter.txt", help="Words file")
```